# image goes upto tmp folder but is not uploaded in product image Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento, file-upload

I updated my website theme and just a week back backend admin product image upload functionality completely stopped working. I am not able to view or upload images at all. I have checked the permissions made changes to Uploader.php in lib it goes up to tmp folder but doesnot upload. my Magento version is mentioned. I tried disabling modules. Adding Dull uploader / Maven HTML5 Uploader none of which seems to work. I have gone through most questions on Stack but no solution seems to work. Any help pointing me towards a good solution is appreciated

Comment: The question may look stupid but anyway : did you check the product folder permissions for your webserver user ?

Comment: Yes I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the theme update may be causing this issue. 
First thing you can try is changing the theme to magento's default theme. 
If this is not helping, you can try going into the image upload page in magento backend and inspect the page, see if there are any error messages.If this isn't helping you can try contacting the theme's support team to help you, or ask them for older version of the theme so you revert it.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks

Comment: But it was working till last week and it suddenly stopped if the theme was causing it, it would have probably stopped when I had activated the theme. it was working a good one month post that

Comment: Ok, you can try checking magento's logs see if there is anything related to the issue.You can find them in /var/log within your root Magento installation

If the directories or files don't exist, create them and give them the correct permissions, then enable logging within Magento by going to System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes After that try uploading the images again on order to log the error.

Comment: You can also check the available disk space on your server. See if this is causing the issue.

Comment: I did check the disk space its only 8% filled

Comment: Can you tell me the size of the images you are trying to upload since there is limit in the php.ini file which is set to 2mb by default. Also try running reindex and clearing the cache.